# Polynomial Orthogonal Complement

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Let $V = \mathbb{P^4}$ denote the space of quartic polynomials, with
>   the $L^2$ inner product $$\langle p,q \rangle = \int^1_{-1}
>  p(x)q(x)dx.$$ Let $W = \mathbb{P^2}$ be the subspace of quadratic
>   polynomials. Find a basis for and the dimension of $W^{\perp}$.

The answer is $$t^3 - \frac{3}{5}t, t^4 - \frac{6}{7}t^2 + \frac{3}{35};\,\, \dim (W^{\perp}) =2$$

How did they get that?

Comment: "Space of quartic polynomials"? Do you mean the space of (real, complex, rational...) polynomials of degree $\,\leq 4\,$ *and* zero?

Comment: @DonAntonio yes i do..

Comment: Which one? Real? Complex?

Comment: @EuYu it doesnt specify but im sure is real

Comment: It must be real or there would be a conjugate inside the inner product...

Comment: How do you find a basis for the orthogonal complement of a polynomial subspace if that subspace is the span of only ONE vector? In other words you aren't able to get a system of equations so how else can you go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, for a finite dimensional vector space we have $\dim W + \dim W^\perp = \dim V$ so that covers the dimension part. For the basis of the orthogonal complement, we have
$$\int_{-1}^1 ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e\ dx = 0$$
$$\int_{-1}^1 x(ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e)\ dx = 0$$
$$\int_{-1}^1x^2(ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e)\ dx = 0$$
Because the standard basis of $\mathbb{P}^2$ must satisfy the orthogonality conditions. Therefore we get
$$\frac{a}{5} + \frac{c}{3}  + e = 0$$
$$\frac{b}{5} + \frac{d}{3} = 0$$
$$\frac{a}{7} + \frac{c}{5} + \frac{e}{3} = 0$$
Solving this system yields 
$$a = \frac{35}{3}e,\ \ b=-\frac{5}{3}d,\ \  c=-10e$$
with two parameters to vary. Your solutions follows by taking $(a=0,\ b=1)$ and $(a=1,\ b=0)$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you, but I am a bit confused I see how this is an orthogonal complement basis but how does it relate to $t^3 - \frac{3}{5}t, t^4 - \frac{6}{7}t^2 + \frac{3}{35}$??

Comment: Take $a=0$ and $b=1$ and solve for $c,\ d,\ e$. See what you get. Remember $a,\ b,\ c,\ d,\ e$ are the coefficients of the standard basis.

Comment: Well, for example choose, as written clearly in the above answer, $$a=1\,,\,b=0\Longrightarrow e=\frac{3}{35}\,,\,d=0\,,\,c=-10e=-\frac{6}{7}\Longrightarrow\, \text{one of the pol's is }\, x^4-\frac{6}{7}x^2+\frac{3}{35}$$ and etc.

Comment: Yup, I understand now with you guys help! One last question, how did you know that a = 1, b = 0 , and vice versa?

Comment: Well, the coefficients kinda have to match. Both your polynomials are monic so those are the natural choices.

Comment: Gotcha. Since they are monic . Thank you very much EuYu!

Answer (score 4):

Well, one way would be to use Gram-Schmidt to produce an orthogonal basis,
starting with the basis $1$, $t$, $t^2$, $t^3$, $t^4$. The result will be five polynomials $p_r(x)$ for $r=0,\ldots,4$ where $p_r$ has degree $r$. So $p_0$, $p_1$ and $p_2$ will span the space of quadratic polynomials and $p_3$ and $p_4$ will span a 2-dimensional space orthogonal to the quadratics. Since we know that the dimension of $W^\perp$ is two (because $\mathrm{dim}(W)+\mathrm{dim}(W^\perp)=5$), we see that $p_3$ and $p_4$ are a basis for $W^\perp$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that.

Answer (score 4):

Let

$$p(x):=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e\in W^\perp$$

Since $W:=\operatorname{Span}\{1,x,x^2\}\,$ , we get:

$$(1)\;\;\;\;\;\;0=\langle\,p\,,\,1\,\rangle=\int_{-1}^1p(x)dx=\frac{2}{5}a+\frac{2}{3}c+2e$$

$$(2)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;0=\langle\,p\,,\,x\,\rangle=\int_{-1}^1xp(x)dx=\frac{2}{5}b+\frac{2}{3}d$$

$$(3)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;0=\langle\,p\,,\,x^2\,\rangle=\int_{-1}^1x^2p(x)dx=\frac{2}{7}a+\frac{2}{5}c+\frac{2}{3}e$$

The above relies on the easy results that the integral on a symmetric (above zero) interval of an even function is twice the value of its primitive on either of the two limits, whereas the same integral of an odd function is zero.

Now solve the above linear system.

Comment: Thank you, but I am a bit confused I see how this is an orthogonal complement basis but how does it relate to $t^3 - \frac{3}{5}t, t^4 - \frac{6}{7}t^2 + \frac{3}{35}$??

Comment: Read my comment below Euyu's answer: it applies exactly the same here.

Comment: I understand now with guys help. Thank you very much , DonAntonio!

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_k(x) = x^k$, $k=0,...,4$. Then $v_k$ is a basis for $\mathbb{P}^4$. (To see this note that any quartic can be written in terms of $v_k$, and if $\sum \alpha_k v_k = 0$, then by differentiating and evaluating at $x=0$ we can see that $\alpha_k = 0$, hence they are linearly independent.)

By the same token, $v_k$, $k=0,1,2$ is a basis for $\mathbb{P}^2$. It follows that $\dim \mathbb{P}^2 = 3$, and since $\mathbb{P}^4 = \mathbb{P}^2 \oplus (\mathbb{P}^2)^\bot$, we see that $\dim (\mathbb{P}^2)^\bot = 2$.

We can find a basis for $(\mathbb{P}^2)^\bot$ by projecting the $v_k$ onto $(\mathbb{P}^2)^\bot$. Clearly $v_k$, $k=0,1,2$ will project to zero. So the only remaining basis elements that need to be projected are $v_3,v_4$.

Note in passing that $\langle v_j, v_k \rangle = \frac{1}{j+k+1}(1-(-1)^{j+k+1})$.

To compute the projection of $x$ onto $(\mathbb{P}^2)^\bot$, we need to determine $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\langle x-\sum_{k=0}^2 \alpha_k v_k, v_j \rangle = 0$ for $j=0,1,2$. This is just the linear system $\langle x, v_j \rangle  = \langle \sum_{k=0}^2 \alpha_k v_k, v_j \rangle$, or
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\langle v_0,  v_0 \rangle & \langle v_1,  v_0 \rangle & \langle v_2, v_0  \rangle \\
\langle v_0,  v_1 \rangle & \langle v_1,  v_1 \rangle & \langle v_2, v_1  \rangle \\
\langle v_0,  v_2 \rangle & \langle v_1,  v_2 \rangle & \langle v_2, v_2  \rangle
\end{bmatrix}
\alpha = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\langle x,  v_0 \rangle \\
\langle x,  v_1 \rangle \\
\langle x,  v_2 \rangle 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Grinding through the computations gives $\alpha = \frac{1}{5} (0,3,0)^T$ when $x=v_3$ and $\alpha = \frac{1}{35} (-3, 0, 30)^T$ when $x=v_4$.

Hence a basis for $(\mathbb{P}^2)^\bot$ is $x \mapsto x^3-\frac{3}{5}x$, $x \mapsto x^4+\frac{3}{35}-\frac{6}{7}x^2$.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much! So there are many ways to do it, instead of just taking the $L^2$ inner product, i could have instead used gram matrix. Thank you for pointing that out , Copper.hat

Comment: You are welcome. Note that you are still taking the inner products, they just happen to be easy to compute for my particular choice of basis, $v_k$.